# What is the polar formula for $y=x$?

Tags: functions, polar-coordinates

$y=x$ is a basic cartesian equation, but I'm at a loss as to what it is in polar form. It seems the only way I've found to express it is with $r$ on both side of the equation, but is there a way of writing it with $r$ on only one side?

Comment: $\theta=\pi/4$ or $\theta=5\pi/4$

Comment: Better still, don't write $r$ at all. You don't need a $y$ in the Cartesian formula for the line $x = 2$, after all.

Comment: @DavidK What???

Comment: Even though you have too coordinates in a coordinate system of the plane, they don't both have to show up in every equation describing every curve in the plane. In the Cartesian plane, the horizontal and vertical lines have only one coordinate in their equations, for example, $x=2$ or $y = -3$. In polar coordinates, a circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin has equation $r = 2$; there is no $\theta$ in that equation. Now what is the shape of all points whose polar coordinates satisfy the equation $\theta = \pi/2$? How about $\theta = \pi/4$?

Answer (score 3):

One way to see it is the following:

Knowing that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and that $y=r\sin(\theta)$, the equation $x=y$ implies the equation:

$$r\cos(\theta)=r\sin(\theta)$$

Subtracting to one side, you get:

$$r\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta) = 0$$

Factoring, we have:

$$r(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta))=0$$

Now, two things multiplied equal zero if and only if at least one of them is zero.  This is true when either $r=0$ or when $(\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta))=0$

This is true whenever $r=0$ and $\theta$ is anything, or when $r$ is anything and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Imagine $(r,\theta)$ to be a set of marching instructions: you turn $\theta$ and march a distance of $r$.

In the case of $y=x$, this line makes a $\frac{\pi}{4}$ angle with the positive $x$ axis. So turn $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and march, well, march however far you'd like. Since we can move any $r$, we leave it unspecified.

$$\theta = \pi/4$$

As mentioned elsewhere, $5\pi/4$ would be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The polar coordinates $\rho,~\theta$ describe $x,~y$ in terms of angle (begining from the positive $x$ axis) and distance (from the zero element). Your curve is $y=x$, the diagonal, which has constant angle $\pi/4$ or $5\pi/4$ (in the case of the first and the third quadrant, respectively). These expressions are exactly the traslation of your curve into polar coordinates. Besides, you can apply $x=\rho\cos\theta, ~y=\rho\sin\theta$ to $y=x$ and get $\tan\theta=1$, meaning that $\theta=\pi/4$ or $5\pi/4$.

Answer (score 0):

Any line through origin in cartesian form has the equation $y=mx$; in polar form it will be given by $\theta = \tan^{-1} (m)$. Exceptionally the $y$-axis is given by $\theta=\pi/2$. Only the lines avoiding the origin will have equations involving both $r$ and $\theta$.